# Expect script to run a command in loop

Tags: tcl, expect

I'm new to expect. I'm trying to run a command in loop.

1. ssh into a machine
2. execute the same  command multiple times

```
package require Expect

set uname admin
set password default
set hostname "182.35.44.35"

#SSH into Appliance
set timeout 10
cd /cygwin/bin 
puts "changed into directory and exec telnet"
spawn telnet "$hostname"

expect "br"
exp_send "admin\r"
expect "Password" 
exp_send "******\r"
expect "br"
exp_send "zzdebugshell\r"
after 1000
send "*******\r"
after 1000
send "*******\r"
expect "debugshell#"
after 1000

set times 0;
while { $times < 10 } 
{
send "vmstat -n 2 5\r"
set times [expr $times+1];
}

expect "debugshell"
exp_send "exit\r"

expect "br"
exp_send "exit\r"
exit
```

`Error : debugshell# child process exited abnormally`

Could you please help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

This section looks wrong:

```
set times 0;
while { $times < 10 } 
{
send "vmstat -n 2 5\r"
set times [expr $times+1];
}
```

You should do an `expect` after that `send` so that you wait for the prompt to come before going round the loop again. Your looping is also non-idiomatic, and putting the brace on a newline simply won't work with Tcl (as newlines are command terminators unless quoted).

The corrected/improved version would be:

```
for {set times 0} {$times < 10} {incr times} {
    send "vmstat -n 2 5\r"
    expect "debugshell"
}
```

You'd also be able to drop the wait for the prompt immediately after the loop, since it's now inside the loop. Of course.

You should also (perhaps) put a `close` and (definitely) a `wait` before the `exit`:

```
exp_send "exit\r"
# Maybe 'expect' something here...
close
wait
exit
```

(Those `expect "br"` lines look odd to me, but maybe they're OK; I don't know what your prompt looks like after all…)